# MERGE giving Node properties cannot be specified in this context message

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I setup my db (Neo4j 2.0 M06) like so:

```
CREATE (alex:Person {Name:'Alex'})
CREATE (alice:Person {Name:'Alice'})
CREATE (brenda:Person {Name:'Brenda'})

CREATE alex-[:KNOWS]->alice
```

Which gives me (as expected) one disconnected node (Brenda) and two connected nodes. Now, I'd like to use `MERGE` to create a relationship between Alex and Brenda, so I try:

```
MATCH (alex:Person { Name:'Alex' }),(brenda:Person { Name:'Brenda' })
MERGE (alex)-[r:KNOWS]->(brenda)
RETURN r
```

Which as far as I can see - is pretty identical to the [documentation example](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-merge.html#merge-merge-on-a-relationship), but then I get the following error:

```
Node properties cannot be specified in this context (line 1, column 20)
"MATCH (alex:Person { Name:'Alex' }),(alice:Person { Name:'Brenda' })"
                    ^
```

By the by - I copy and paste the documentation example into my DB UI I get the same error.

I can't use a `WHERE` clause as:

```
MERGE only supports single node patterns
```

I presume I have got the `MERGE` statement wrong... but how?

Comment: The "milestone" docs now point to the latest 2.0 version, which is 2.0-RC1, and the examples are only valid for that version. I get a bit confused sometimes by the versions of the documentation, but I think that's the problem here: run the release candidate and your query should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATCH with properties and MERGE with relationships are available first in 2.0-RC1.